# Restrict the number of nodes used by an Azure Machine Learning pipeine

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have written a pipeline that I want to run on a remote compute cluster within Azure Machine Learning. My aim is to process a large amount of historical data, and to do this I will need to run the pipeline on a large number of input parameter combinations.

Is there a way to restrict the number of nodes that the pipeline uses on the cluster? By default it will use all the nodes available to the cluster, and I would like to restrict it so that it only uses a pre-defined maximum. This allows me to leave the rest of the cluster free for other users.

My current code to start the pipeline looks like this:

```
# Setup the pipeline
steps = [data_import_step] # Contains PythonScriptStep
pipeline = Pipeline(workspace=ws, steps=steps)
pipeline.validate()

# Big long list of historical dates that I want to process data for
dts = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01', freq='6H', closed='left')
# Submit the pipeline job
for dt in dts:
    pipeline_run = Experiment(ws, 'my-pipeline-run').submit(
        pipeline,
        pipeline_parameters={
            'import_datetime': dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:00'),
        }
    )
```

Comment: For example, you want the pipeline to use a max of 2 nodes on a 4-node cluster? Is this an `AMLCompute` cluster? Also, what kind of step is your `data_import_step`? If it is a `PythonScriptStep` it will only run on one node by default.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  It is an `AMLCompute` cluster. Each `PythonScriptStep` only uses one node, but let's say I submit 100 pipeline runs with different parameter settings, I'd like a way to prevent this from using the entire capacity of the cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the killer feature of Azure ML is not having to worry about load balancing like this. Our team has a compute target with `max_nodes=100` for every feature branch and we have `Hyperdrive` pipelines that result in 130 runs for each pipeline.

We can submit multiple `PipelineRun`s back-to-back and the orchestrator does the heavy lifting of queuing, submitting, all the runs so that the `PipelineRun`s execute in the serial order I submitted them, and that the cluster is never overloaded. This works without issue for us 99% of the time.

If what you're looking for is that you'd like the `PipelineRun`s to be executed in parallel, then you should check out [`ParallelRunStep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-parallel-run-step#build-and-run-the-pipeline-containing-parallelrunstep).

Another option is to isolate your computes. You can have up to 200 `ComputeTarget`s per workspace. Two 50-node `ComputeTarget`s cost the same as one 100-node `ComputeTarget`.

On our team, we use [`pygit2`](https://www.pygit2.org/) to have a `ComputeTarget` created for each feature branch, so that, as data scientists, we can be confident that we're not stepping on our coworkers' toes.

Comment: Are the runs always executed in serial order of when they are submitted? e.g. If I submit jobs that will occupy the full cluster for 12 hours, will my colleague have to wait 12 hours before any jobs that they then submit will start?

Comment: AFAIK, `Runs` are submitted in a serial order, but 1) `PipelineRun`s (with sequence of `Run`s) and 2) `Run`s that run on multiple nodes makes it harder to know deterministically.

Comment: @tobycoleman added another recommendation about isolating `ComputeTarget`s to avoid blocking colleagues.